# Get to know which field/column got update/edit in a list

Tags: sharepoint-online, version-history, itemupdated

Using SharePoint online.

I have custom form (CSS + JS) that add/update/delete item from a SharePoint list. This form is linked with multiple master list to provide drop downs.

Now my customer need an email notification whenever any data get added or field get updated for any existing record. That email should carry the details about field in which data get added or updated, along with the previous data.

I am not sure how to build this solution, should I create a sub-transaction list which carry replica of existing records and on every update workflow will compare it with newly update record field by field.

Or there is any solution for using SharePoint version history to achieve this..  any suggestion on it !

Answer (score 4):

You can use the good-old SharePoint alerts to track what fields were changed.

**Set up alerts**

- List > Alert me

[image]

- Choose the alerts title, recepient, changes you want to track and the schedule:

[image]

**This is what a sample form looks like**

[image]

**Email you'll get when updated were made**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for suggestion..  is there any provision to save all these change history in some list in SharePoint ?

Comment: not out of the box, no.

Comment: Thank you Denis

Comment: Actually if you have version control on your list you should be able to see previous edits. The Alert is just displaying the most recent updates based upon the frequency you request. To reduce email transactions, a daily summary is pretty great.